# Using a plist located in documents directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Im copying the plist array of dictionaries to documents directory on the device like this:

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(copyPlist)];
    return YES;
}

- (void)copyPlist {

    NSError *error;

    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString *doumentDirectoryPath=[pathsArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *destinationPath= [doumentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Wine.plist"];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]){
        NSLog(@"database localtion %@",destinationPath);
        return;
    }

    NSString *sourcePath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Wine" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSLog(@"source path %@",sourcePath);
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];
    }
```

Log for database location:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/832E16F4-A204-457E-BFF0-6AEA27915C25/Documents/Wine.plist
```

---

Then, I'm trying to access the plist and fill sortedWines array with the dictionaries to populate a TableView:

TableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WinesViewController : UITableViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate> {
     NSMutableArray *sortedWines;
}

@end
```

TableViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Wine.plist"];
    NSLog(@"plist path %@", path);

    sortedWines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"objects %@", sortedWines);


    NSSortDescriptor * sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Popularity" ascending:YES];
    [sortedWines sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The log for plist path:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/832E16F4-A204-457E-BFF0-6AEA27915C25/Documents/Wine.plist
```

and the log for objects:

(null)

How to fill the sortedWines array with objects now?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Do you want to know how to fill an NSArray with your Wine.plist file or do you need to know how to copy a plist, etc.?

Comment: Well when I run my app it looks like the plist is copyed, the path is accessed in viewDidLoad, but my NSMutableArray *sortedWines; isn't populated with the dictionaries from the plist. I have the sortedWines array and I want the array to contain the plist array with dictionaries so I can sort them and populate the tableview.

Comment: Is your root object an array or a dictionary?

Comment: Plist = array filled with dictionaries.

Comment: You should log your copyItemAtPath:toPath: to see if it returns YES (or 1) to know if the copy was successful.  If it was not, you should log error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is that your original plist file in your bundle is not structured as an array of dictionaries.

To settle this assertion add a few more lines to your copyPlist method:

```
NSString *sourcePath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Wine" ofType:@"plist"];
NSLog(@"source path %@",sourcePath);
NSMutableArray *sortedWines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:sourcePath];
NSLog(@"objects %@", sortedWines); // bet this is nil too
```

EDIT

So once you know you have the file above then you need to view/test

[fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];

The problem here is you do not check the return code but blindly assume success. So look at return code and log error in it fails. Once you know that is working then also add another line just after the copy to load the file into an array as your viwDidLoad does (copy the code).

If that works but file is missing at viewDidLoad then the only possible is you or the system is deleting all files in the documents directory (I have heard if your app uses iCloud the rules for this folder change.

PS: why are you doing this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(copyPlist)];
```

Instead of:

```
[self copyPlist];
```

Comment: If I add those lines (and comment the if-statement so it reaches through) and run, the sortedWines are filled with the objects. But if I go to the TableViewController, here the sortedWines are still (null)